# Check when code run on local machine or on EC2 in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have a code that I want to run in global.asax in ASP.NET. I want this code to run only on localhost and when the code on an EC2 instance, I want it to run another code (the second code should run when I deploy my project on Amazon Web Service EC2 server), how can I do that without using the DEBUG functionality?

Comment: Do you usinglocal IIS express or old Visual Studio dev server (cassini) on your DEV machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for whether or not the request is from the local machine, do this:

```
bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;

if(isLocal)
{
    // Do things that should only be done when request is local here

}
```

> Note: Read [HttpRequest.IsLocal documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks but I meant something else. Checking whether the machine that the current site is running on is an EC2 machine not my laptop computer. Maybe there is a server variable to access to that tells us that the computer is an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I guess uyou can pick few environment variables frm these:
Environment Variables (type ENV)
EC2_AMI_ID
EC2_AKI_ID
EC2_ARI_ID
EC2_AMI_MANIFEST_PATH
EC2_PLACEMENT_AVAILABILITY_ZONE
EC2_HOSTNAME
EC2_INSTANCE_ID
EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE
EC2_LOCAL_HOSTNAME
EC2_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME
EC2_PUBLIC_IPV4
EC2_RESERVATION_ID
EC2_SECURITY_GROUPS
RS_EIP
RS_SERVER
RS_SKETCHY
RS_SYSLOG
RS_TOKEN
RS_SERVER_NAME
List taken from here: https://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0013_-_What_EC2_environment_variables_are_available_in_RightScripts%3F

I think, that checking for availability of EC2_AMI_ID and EC2_INSTANCE_ID would be enough to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET dev server (VS 2012 and earlier) use this method:

```
public static bool IsDebugWebServer()
{
  if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
  {
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] == null || HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] == string.Empty;
  }
else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And if you are using local IIS Express use this:

```
public static bool IsDebugWebServer()
{
  return String.Compare(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, "iisexpress") == 0;
}
```